# Hotelling's t-squared statistic with PCA

Tags: python, statistics, pca

I'm trying to calculate Hotelling's t-squared statistic in Python after performing a PCA and only keeping two composants. I'm using sklearn and numpy.

```
def get_pca(X, n=2, scale=True):
    if scale:
        scale = StandardScaler()
        scale.fit(X)
        X_scaled = scale.transform(X)
    else:
        X_scaled = X
    
    pca = PCA(n_components=n)
    pca.fit(X_scaled)
    return scale, pca, pca.transform(X_scaled)

def get_mu(T):
    return [np.mean(T[:, k]) for k in range(T.shape[1])]

def get_SD(pcs, mu):
    sigma = np.linalg.inv(np.cov(pcs.T))

    SD = np.zeros(len(pcs), dtype='float')
    for i in range(len(pcs)):
        temp = np.subtract(pcs[i], mu)
        SD[i] = temp.dot(sigma).dot(temp.T)

    return SD
```

But I think that something is wrong with this. Is the calculation correct in my code?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the calculation?